# CSS Rule Priorities

Tags: css

Given the following mark-up...

```
<div id="Header">
     <a href="#" class="Highlight">foo</a>
</div>
```

And the following stylesheet...

```
/******************Exceptions******************/
#Footer, #Header,
#Footer a, #Header a { color: #f8f8f8; }


/******************Classes******************/
.Highlight, a.Highlight { color: #B1D355; }
.Notification, a.Notification { color: Red; }
```

**Why is my link still off-white (F8F8F8) rather than green (B1D355)?**

Shouldn't using the class *Highlight* override the color settings for *Header* and *Footer* since it comes after their declarations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's all about weight. A class selector gets trumped by an ID selector.

```
#Footer a
```

will always get precedence over

`.Highlight` or `.Highlight a`

Make your selector

```
#Footer .highlight a
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Yep, and http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/ gives a decent "in depth" explanation.

Comment: Figured. I guess I'll need to rethink my style structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

#### CSS priority

1. ID selector > class selector > attribute selector
2. For the same priority, the later has the higher priority.

   > .class1 {
   >      color: black;
   >   }
   >
   > .class2 {
   >      color: red;
   >   }

   It will be red.
3. To have more priority, use `!important`

---

For your problem, `#Footer` is an ID selector has higher priority than `.Highlight`, a class selector.

Comment: The [use of `!important` should be considered very carefully](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 2):

ID has a higher priority than class in CSS:

Use `#Header a.Highlight { color: #B1D355; }`

Answer (score 1):

CSS rules are not just applied based on the "last parsed, last applied".  It also depends on how specific and unique the rule is to that element.  Since you're only specifying a `class` selector, the path that included the `id` is getting a higher priority.