# CSS doesn't work the same when moving internal stylesheet to external

Tags: css, height, border, external, internal

I designed a layout, that you can see [here](http://www.cinecount.com/bbso.html), with a fixed header, a fixed menubar, contents inside boxes arranged in two columns, and a footer, plus a border around the whole `<body>` element. It works exactly as I want (tested with Iceweasel 38.2 and Internet Explorer 11).

The problem is: when I try to move the style sheet to an external css file, it doesn't work any more. The result looks like [this](http://www.cinecount.com/bb.html).

I can't understand why the appearance of the page changes since the styles and the html are exactly the same. Thje external CSS does not contain the   tags.

This is the source css/html for the working page:

```
<style>

  body    {
      height: 100%;
      color: black;
      background: white;
      border-width: 4px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width:1024px;
      }

  #left {       
      margin:0;
      margin-right: -4px;
      margin-top: 183px;
      padding:0;
      float:left;
      width:65%;
      background:red; 
      }

  #right {    
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      margin-top: 183px;
      float:right;
      width:calc(35% + 4px);
      left: -4px;
      background:blue;
      }


  .boxleft { 
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      padding-left:20px;
      padding-right:20px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color:black;
      border-top-width:0px;
      border-left-width:0px;
      border-right-width:4px;
      border-bottom-width:4px; 
      float:left;
      width:calc(100% - 44px); 
      }

  .title {      
      background-color:blue;   
      color:white;
      } 

  .rating {     
      background-color:red;  
      color:white;
      }

  .boxright {    
      padding:20px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color:black;
      border-top-width:0px;
      border-left-width:4px;
      border-right-width:0px;
      border-bottom-width:4px; 
      float:right;
      width:calc(100% - 44px); 
      }

  .poster {     
      background-color:green;    
      color:white;
      } 

  #header { 
      background-image:url('Title background03.png');  
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      position:fixed;
      width: 100%;
      max-width:1024px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      height:119px;
      top: 0;
      } 


  #footer { 
      background:white; 
      position:fixed;
      width:100%; 
      max-width:1024px;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 0px;
      border-top-style: solid;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-color:black;
      border-top-width:4px;
      border-bottom-width:4px;
      } 

  #menu {       
      background:black; 
      position:fixed;
      color:white;
      width:100%; 
      max-width:calc(1024px - 24px);             
      z-index:200;  
      margin: 0px auto;
      top:115px;
      height:64px;
      padding-top:12px;
      padding-left:24px;
      /* z-index: 1; */
      }

</style>    



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>       
  </head>

  <body>

<div id="header">
</div>

<p id="menu">menu1 - menu2 - menu3</p>
<div id="left">
  <div class="title boxleft">
    <p>title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rating boxleft">
    <p>rating</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <div class="poster boxright">
    <p>poster</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <P>copyright</P>
</div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: had you link properly external css to html  page....

Comment: The CSS is different in each example - eg body in one lists a white border, the other requests black.

Comment: I have  make this demo it work fine in  my case ...... with  external  css....

Comment: Add css Code in demo.css file and in html head section put <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

style.css is the name of your external css file

Edited: For your problem with the border not taking up the entire page try:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

BTW < style> tags usually go in the head and not in front of the < !DOCTYLE html> tag

Comment: Thanks for the tip about <style> tags positioning. The non-working file has a <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bb.css"></link> line in its head. The problem is that the border around the 'body' element is not visible with the external CSS or, better, it is there (you can see it at the very top of the page), but it is like it is around a 0 heigth element.

Comment: This sounds crazy but if, in the working html file, I  put the internal style sheet inside the 'head' section, as it should be done, the border around the 'body' element disappears as in the non-working example I linked to in my original post. On the other hand, if, in the non-working example, I move the  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bb.css"></link> before the !DOCTYPE tag, then everything works fine! I don't think this is compliant to CSS specifications. But it works both with Mozilla and IE...

Comment: I edited my response. In your external css file add that line of css.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Why it worked, even without the html 100% height rule, when the styles were before the '!DOCTYPE html' tag remains a mistery, but who cares...

Comment: Glad it worked for you the proper way. If you can upvote my solution that would be great.

Comment: I did, but due to my low reputation it doesn't show for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered CSS priority rules or so-called *weights*?

There is an in-depth explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Also, Answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876575/css-rule-priorities) might me helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's a matter of priority. The external CSS doesn't work even with the !important rule. It seems that, when moving styles to the external css, the 'body' element shrinks to 0 height, which doesn't make sense to me.