# CSS styles doesn't change after adding class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a selection menu and I want to change the background color of a button when it is clicked. I'm using the below code to apply the `sort-select-active` class to the `div` with `sort-select` id:

```js
var selected = false;
var select= document.getElementById('sort-select')
select.onclick = (e) => {
   selected = !selected;
   if (selected)
      select.classList.add("sort-select-active");
   else 
      select.classList.remove("sort-select-active");
};
```

```css
#sort-select {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.sort-select-active {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="sort-contain">
 <div id="sort-select">
   Selected
  </div>
</div>
```

The class is successfully added to the element, but the background color doesn't change. Is there a conflict between the different background colors defined?

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2876596/562359

Comment: IDs have a priority over classes. So #sort-select is always overwriting the added class.

Comment: You haven't defined a variable called `select`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set a `background-color` via an `id`, then you set another via a `class`, the first one will always be applied, because it has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Change `#sort-select` selector by a `class` in your CSS, or use inline styling like this:

```js
var selected = false;
select.onclick = (e) => {
    selected = !selected;
    if (selected)
      slect.style.backgroundColor ="gray"
    else 
     slect.style.backgroundColor ="lightgray"
};
```

Also you could use `!important` keyword, like so :

```css
.sort-select-active {
  background-color: grey!important;
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to change the priority?

Comment: I think so, by adding `!important` key word. I edited my answer, take a look.

Comment: You could also change your CSS selector to `#sort-select.sort-select-active`

Comment: Thanks, both your answers work

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. I added `!important` in the css class

```js
var select = document.getElementById("sort-select")
var selected = false;

select.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  selected = !selected;
  if (selected) {
    select.classList.add("sort-select-active");
  } else {
    select.classList.remove("sort-select-active");
  }

});
```

```css
#sort-select {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.sort-select-active {
  background-color: grey !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="sort-contain">
  <div id="sort-select">
    Selected
  </div>
</div>
```